# Controlling an input/output box via php/javascript

Tags: php, javascript, input, device

i have a php/javascript webbased application running on a hosted server (dreamhost), and im looking to setup an input output box in-house that can take an identifier from the php application and trigger a specific output based on the trigger.

For example. Lets say i have an input/output device with 10 outputs. And i have 10 records in my php application. I want to say, "when record #1 is being viewed, activate output #1 on the input/output box"

Are there any input/output boxes that can be triggered via php or javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can save input and output values in some sort of database on server. Your "input/output box" should contact with hosted server for getting output values and sending input values.

When users access server with web browser, you can serve input values which sent from "i/o box" and users can change output values too. When an output changes, next time "i/o box's" request to server receives new output values and changes it's output states according these values.

Here's the summary:

1. Your i/o box should have web request capability (Ethernet controller and tcp/ip stack or equivalents of these).
2. Your PHP script should handle i/o box's request and writes i/o box's input values to database. Also PHP script should respond with output values which are stored in database too.
3. Your PHP script should handle user requests. User can view input values and send requests for changing output values. Your PHP script should handle output change requests and write them to database.
4. Your i/o box need to do request to your server. This way it can send new input values and receive new output values.